# Lenovo dock HDMI audio external monitor

Tags: sound, lenovo, hdmi

I got a Lenovo T440s and a docking station, where the docking station is connected to a monitor ([specs](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c01869172)) with internal speakers through HDMI.

My problem is I cannot seem to be able to change the audio output from the laptop speakers to my monitor´s speakers (as can be seen in the screenshot below, there is no HDMI option).

[image]

My laptop does not have a HDMI input, only my dock has. I suspect this is the reason why it is not detected and shown in the sound options.

Any help or insight appreciated.

Regards

**Edit**

```
sudo aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: HDMI [HDA Intel HDMI], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3232 Analog [ALC3232 Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Edit 2**

Pavucontrol output devices

[image]

Pavucontrol configuration profiles 1

[image]

Pavucontrol configuration profiles 2

[image]

Comment: You probably need some drivers from the manufacturer.

Comment: Not very helpful, but with my T430s and docking station, I definitely get an HDMI / DisplayPort 3 option for audio output... (and the T430s has no hdmi output either)

Comment: Also, you can find information on http://www.thinkwiki.org (just in case you don't know of the site)

Answer (score 0):

In this window click on Analog Stereo Output.
There would be option like HDMI+Analog Stereo Output(or Duplex).

Comment: That option is not present, as the HDMI port on the dock is not detected

Comment: Hi. What shows in terminal this command: sudo aplay -l ?

Comment: updated original question with aplay output

Comment: Try to add you in audio, video groups. Because by default in pavucontrol(program on screenshot) should be "Configuration" tab. There should  be my solution.

Comment: Tried adding my user to audio and video, didnt work. 
Still no HDMI

Comment: Have rebooted? Also try to start pavucontrol from terminal. Because there should be Configuration tab.

Comment: Yea, starting pavucontrol from terminal gives more options. 
Now i see the configuration tab. I got no  HDMI+Analog Stereo Output(or Duplex) option. It says HDMI(unplugged)

Comment: Your T440s has integrated or also discrete graphics card?

Comment: Only integrated - supports hdmi 1.4

Comment: Try to plug your monitor in dock. Next plug laptop in dock and try, like @alci say, use output 3. Also check if speakers in monitor are off.

Comment: Tried to unplug everything and connect it in every possible order. Nothing seems to fix the issue. I appreciate your help, but im afraid the problem still persist

Comment: What ubuntu do you have? And can you try to connect to monitor via Displayport? As workaround?

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04
My monitor does not support displayport

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried alsamixer?

Open up Terminal, then type alsamixer and press Enter.

You will get an odd sort of panel with all your output and input devices listed across the bottom, and a vertical display of the sound levels.

Left and right arrows pan through the list of sound devices, and up and down arrows increase or decrease the sound levels.

When you're dome making adjustments, just press Esc (the escape key) to exit.

Also read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alsamixer